# How to run commands on same TCL shell using Python

Tags: python, tcl

I am having all the libraries written in TCL. I want to create a GUI in Python which will have few buttons and other options. In the start TCL shell will open. When I will click the buttons, respective commands will be executed on the TCL shell.

Is it possible to fire commands on the same shell of TCL without closing TCL shell.

I searched google and find `Tkniter` module in Python but it will open TCL shell everytime I need to execute command.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're Doing It Wrong if you're making a new interpreter each time you want to run a command. That's maximising the amount of overhead, which is ridiculous.

Comment: @DonalFellows I read it as he is asking how to use a single TCL interpreter process. E.g. explicitly not launching a new process each time.

Comment: No I dont want to make new interpreter each time. I want to run commands on the same old TCL shell

Comment: I do this sort of thing using  `os.startfile(cmd)` where, for example, `cmd = 'copy myfile.txt  C:\\Users\\Philip\\Desktop'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use Tkinter to run a series of commands in the same Tcl interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 28 2016, 05:52:45) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> root.tk.eval('set msg "hello world"')
'hello world'
>>> root.tk.eval('string length $msg')
'11'
>>> root.tk.eval('foreach x {1 2 4} {puts "$msg $x"}')
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 4
''
>>>
```

- here the variable msg is set in one command and its value is used in later commands, which would not work if we were creating a new interpreter for each command.
If you don't want the Tk window that gets created, just run `root.tk.eval('wm withdraw .')` to hide it.

If this doesn't answer your question you had better explain what else it is that you need :-)

Comment: Fun fact: It's possible to use tkinter without creating the root window. The `Tk` class takes a keyword argument named `useTk`. If you set it to `False` you'll get a tcl interpreter without tk.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using [Pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html)

> Pexpect is a Python module for spawning child applications and controlling
>   them automatically. Pexpect can be used for automating interactive applications
>   such as ssh, ftp, passwd, telnet, etc. It can be used to a automate setup
>   scripts for duplicating software package installations on different servers. It
>   can be used for automated software testing. Pexpect is in the spirit of Don
>   Libes' Expect, but Pexpect is pure Python. Other Expect-like modules for Python
>   require TCL and Expect or require C extensions to be compiled. Pexpect does not
>   use C, Expect, or TCL extensions. It should work on any platform that supports
>   the standard Python pty module. The Pexpect interface focuses on ease of use so
>   that simple tasks are easy.

Usage example taken directly from the Pexpect website

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline (mypassword)
```

you can spawn the terminal as a child process and then use this child to send commands when GUI generates an event.

Comment: The questioner says he has libraries already written in Tcl which he needs to call from Python.  Expect-style functionality is irrelevant here.

Comment: Yes that is true however I think it can be accomplished by associating the events generated on clicking a button on Python GUI with expect statements.

Comment: Please expand on it if there is something I am missing over here

Answer (score 0):

I created this simple tcl program `pgm.tcl`

```
puts "Hello world"
```

I can launch it in a console

```
tclsh pgm.tcl
```

Here is how it can be launched in python

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen( ['tclsh', 'pgm.tcl'], stdout=PIPE )
p1out, p1err = p1.communicate()
if p1out is not None: print (p1out)
if p1err is not None: print (p1err)
```

This answer is OS dependent (linux), but you should be able to adapt it to other OS.